# Selecting files by date and containing text, Python

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to select specific files in Windows within a specified timeframe, and if it includes specific text.

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(r'C:\User\Documents\Reports'):

    for file in filenames:
            if os.path.getmtime(file) < datetime.timedelta(days=31) AND if 'Summary' in file or 'Summaries' in file :
                    try: shutil.copy(os.path.join(folderName, file), r'C:\User\Documents\File_Selections')
                    except: 
                            print(folderName, file)
```

So I'm looking through the Reports folder for each file that was last modified in the last month, AND if it's name includes 'summary' or 'summaries'. I then want to copy each file to a specific folder and print out the results.

My main problem is how does the date comparison work, so that only files modified in the last month are selected? Also I was unsure if the AND operator is being used correctly within the 'if' statement.

Comment: You don't need the `if` keyword after the `and` keyword. The `and` is correct. You are selecting all files in the directory that are not older than a month AND they contain either 'summary' or 'summaries'

Comment: `file`is a built-in function, so you should find another identifier for your variable.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `if` keyword after the `and` keyword. The `and` is correct. You are selecting all files in the directory that are not older than a month AND they contain either 'summary' or 'summaries'

The line 
`if os.path.getmtime(file) < datetime.timedelta(days=31) and 'Summary' in file or 'Summaries' in file:`
won't be working, since os.path.getmtime() returns a float.

What you need to do is to use `total_seconds()` after the call to `datetime.timedelta`.
For example,

`if os.path.getmtime(file) < datetime.timedelta(days=31).total_seconds()`

`total_seconds()` will return the `datetime.timedelta` value as a `float`

Comment: Thanks for that. I've taken your input and the comment to the post. Now I have 
if os.path.getmtime(summ) < datetime.timedelta(days=31).total_seconds() AND 'Summary' in summ or 'Summaries' in summ:

Although this throws an invalid syntax error.

Comment: The file time is a Unix timestamp -- the number of seconds since 1970-01-01. A timestamp for 31 days ago is `t_31_days_ago = (datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=31)).timestamp()`. Look for files modified after this time, i.e. `os.path.getmtime(file) > t_31_days_ago`.